# SQL Server : how read variable value from file

Tags: sql-server, variables

I got a simple query in SQL Server like:

```
Update Account 
set Auth = 1 
where UserNumber = (and here i need the value to be read from a list on a text file)
```

Text file format:

```
123  
234  
456
```

One `UserNumber` per row in the text file.

Not experience with this but i assume i need to read UserNumber from a variable and that variable will have to take the values from the text file one by one.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to do it:

Create temporary table:

```
DROP TABLE #UserNumberTemp
CREATE TABLE #UserNumberTemp( 
  [UserNumber] int
)
```

Builk import data into temporary table (assumption is that your data file is .csv)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 BULK INSERT #InterpreterTrimNumbers FROM 'C:\MyData\UserNumber.csv' WITH (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
        ERRORFILE = 'C:\MyData\UserNumberErrors.csv',
        TABLOCK
      )
 --Then based on temporary table do update:

 Update Account set Auth = 1 where UserNumber = (select UserNumber from #UserNumberTemp where #UserNumberTemp.UserNumber = Account.UserNumber)
Commit Transaction
```

Comment: `firstrow` might need to be `1`, as the example text file had no header. The query should probably use an `inner join`, or at least `in (subquery)` instead of `= (subquery)`

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is writing a client side program accessing SQLServer in C#, Java, Python, or any other language you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLCMD mode [variable substitution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx):

```
Update Account 
set Auth = 1 
where UserNumber = $(userNumber)
```

Then use cmd [`for`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) command to iterate the file and pass the value to `sqlcmd`:

```
c:\>for /F %i in (myfile) do slqcmd \
   "update ... where UserNumber = $(userNumber)" \
   -v userNumber=%i
```

Of course, issuing statements one by one like this is not very efficient and there are far better solutions, eg. using [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx).